# Where should I view Console.log result in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, console.log

I am having the following code:

```
var vocabularies = new MyDataService.myService();
vocabularies.success(function (data) {
     console.log(data);                                    
}).error(function (data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

Where can I view the value of data instead of debugging the above code?

Comment: in console only.. :D rightClick-> inspect element.. and there you are...

Comment: in Chrome click on view area -> Inspect Element -> Sources Tab. Here u will find the sources

Comment: If you don't want to use the developer console, try using alert(data).

Comment: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: In Angular Way!! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log

Answer (score 3):

If you want to view the data present in the console then you may use keyboard shortcut **Ctrl + Shift + J** to bring focus on the console.
If you want to see your data during execution you may use alert instead of console.log.

If you want to bind your data to the HTML you need to use

```
    $scope.variable=data;
```

you can then get your value by using expression tag in HTML.

```
    {{variable}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign your data to a $scope variable. And on template you can view it. Find below code:

```
var vocabularies = new MyDataService.myService();
vocabularies.success(function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   $scope.viewData = data;                                    
}).error(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  $scope.viewData = data;
});
```

And then on the template:

```
{{viewData | json}}
```

The above will print it in json format if its json else normal text